# Retrofit null error in call method

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm want to get the last id from MySQL database by retrofit but when the run project has an error from call method value tested with the postman and get value

APIClient.java :

```
public class APIClient {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://**********/Api/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

APIIinterface.java :

```
public interface APIIinterface {

@POST("Agahi/getlastid.php")
Call<AgahiLastId> getAgahiLastId(); }
```

AgahiLastId.java :

```
public class AgahiLastId {

    @SerializedName("agahi_id")
    private int agahi_id;

    public int getAgahi_id() {
        return agahi_id;
    }

    public void setAgahi_id(int agahi_id) {
        this.agahi_id = agahi_id;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private APIIinterface apiIinterface;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Call<AgahiLastId> agahiLastIdCall = apiIinterface.getAgahiLastId();

agahiLastIdCall.enqueue(new Callback<AgahiLastId>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<AgahiLastId> call, Response<AgahiLastId> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("lts","ok");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<AgahiLastId> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});}
```

**I have the error from this line:**

```
Call<AgahiLastId> agahiLastIdCall = apiIinterface.getAgahiLastId();
```

error log :

```
 Attempt to invoke the interface method 'retrofit2. Call app.zagroszoom.mseif.com.zagroszoom.webService.APIIinterface.getAgahiLastId()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Your `apiIinterface` is null. Post your initialization code

Comment: private APIIinterface apiIinterface;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the line.
     APIIinterface apiIinterface = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

```
After that  you can call the own method.

Call<AgahiLastId> agahiLastIdCall = apiIinterface.getAgahiLastId();

agahiLastIdCall.enqueue(new Callback<AgahiLastId>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<AgahiLastId> call, Response<AgahiLastId> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("lts","ok");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<AgahiLastId> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});}
```

Comment: every thing are ok but I don't know why run 'onFailure'

Comment: test this POST Api `http://**********/Api/Agahi/getlastid.php` using postman or any other client to make sure it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following to your `Mainactivity` inside `onCreate` before `Call<AgahiLastId> agahiLastIdCall = apiIinterface.getAgahiLastId();`

```
apiIinterface= APIClient.getClient().create(APIIinterface.class);
```

Learn more about `Retrofit` [here](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial)

Comment: every thing are ok but I don't know why run 'onFailure'

Comment: add `t.printStackTrace();` to your `onFailure` or `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to your retrofit instance and see what error you get